# Herança de templates com django

Tags: python, django, template

Estou tendo um certo problema em aplicar a heraça de templates com o django. Aparentemente esta tudo certo porém meu html filho não é renderizado no template

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple MOOC - Uma simples plataforma de ensino a distância" />
    <title>Simple MOOC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/styles.css'%}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-fixed pure-menu-horizontal">
        <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="">SIMPLE MOOC</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="#">Início</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cursos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <div class="footer">
        Simple MOOC - Uma simples plataforma de ensino a distância
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="splash">
        <div class="pure-g-r">
            <div class="pure-u-1">
                <div class="l-box splash-text">
                    <h1 class="splash-head">
                        Uma Simples Plataforma de Ensino a Distância
                    </h1>
                    <h2 class="splash-subhead">
                        O Simple MOOC visa simplificar o ensino a distância, provendo ferramentas objetivas e de fácil uso para cursos a distância.
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="pure-button primary-button">Saiba mais</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
        <div class="pure-u-2-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <h4 class="content-subhead">Vídeo-aulas e materiais digitais</h4>
                <h3>Publique suas aulas</h3>
                <p>
                    O Simple MOOC tem um sistema simples e prático para que o professor disponibilize vídeo-aulas e materiais digitais como: pdf, slides, imagens ...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250"
                     alt="Vídeo aulas e materiais digitais.">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
        <div class="pure-u-1-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250"
                     alt="Fórum de Dúvidas">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-2-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <h4 class="content-subhead">Fórum de Dúvidas</h4>
                <h3>Interaja com seus Alunos</h3>
                <p>
                    No Simple MOOC você pode ter seu próprio sistema de fórum para que seus alunos possam interagir com você e com os outros alunos
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
        <div class="pure-u-2-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <h4 class="content-subhead">Exercícios</h4>
                <h3>Crie exercícios para avaliar seus alunos</h3>
                <p>
                    Você pode criar exercícios para que os alunos possam ser avaliados e todo o controle de notas e resolução dos exercícios é controlado pela plataforma, facilitando sua vida
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-1-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250"
                     alt="Exercícios">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
        <div class="pure-u-1-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250"
                     alt="Mural de Avisos">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-u-2-3">
            <div class="l-box">
                <h4 class="content-subhead">Mural de Avisos</h4>
                <h3>Envie anúncios diretamente para os alunos</h3>
                <p>
                    Organize os avisos do seu curso de forma fácil e simples.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Qual template sua view está renderizando, o base ou o home?

Comment: Nesse caso Diogo, você teria de fazer o processo inverso e chamar a 'home' em sua view.
Tive uma duvida semelhate a sua [vale a pena dar uma olhada.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240117/heran%C3%A7a-de-templates-n%C3%A3o-esta-funcionando)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o caminho completo ne extends. Ex: 
**{% extends 'core/site/base.html' %}**

A hierarquia deve ser template/core/site/base.html

Answer (score 0):

Comece pelo settings.py, se esta devidamente especificados o **DEBUG** e
**templates** e o que se refere aos arquivos **estáticos**

```
 DEBUG = True # em desenvolvimento
  
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'suaAplicação',
 ]


 TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['templates'],# < onde encontrara os templates
             ......

    STATIC_URL = '/static/' #arquivos estáticos 
    STATIC_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR,' staticfiles')

     ]
```

Okay....

Cada aplicação possui uma pasta chamada **"**templates**"** , contida nela pode haver paginas ou arquivos com pagina base.html e ola.html e index.html

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- dentro da pasta templates, dentro da aplicação, cada aplicação tera uma pasta templates -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stilos.css' %}">


  </head>

  <body>


{%block content %} {% endblock %}
  
 
    <script src="{% static 'scripts.js'%}"></script>    
   <!-- Dentro da pasta static dentro da aplicação -->
  </body>
```

ola.html

```
 {% load static %} <!--- caso tenho arquivos estático na pagina -->
    
    <h3>Ola</h3>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

 {%block content %}
    {% include 'hola.html' %}
{% endblock  %}
```

Dessa forma dividi o template em 3 partes a base, o conteúdo e o index.

Entre apenas 2.

base.html

{% block content %} {% endblock %}

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}  {% endblock %}
```

na view apenas indique o index.html

Quando criado usando

> django-admin startproject .

o espaço e depois ponto indica que criara o projeto sem subpastas, dentro do diretório que quer o projeto

```
.Pasta_projeto
|_projeto
|_aplicações
  |_templates
  |_static
  |_ view..admin
|_aplicação2
  |_templates
  |_static
  |_ de mais arquivos dj
```

qia

Answer (score 0):

Se a pagina estiver sendo sendo carrega, mas em branco normalmente provavelmente é o return da view, que deve estar com o base, tenta troca para o caminho do home.

Ao invés de colocar:

```
def index(request):
return render(request,'.../base.html')
```

coloque:

```
def index(request):
return render(request,'.../home.html')
```

consegui resolver o mesmo problema com a ajuda deste post:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240117/herança-de-templates-não-esta-funcionando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240117/heran%C3%A7a-de-templates-n%C3%A3o-esta-funcionando)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).