# Herança de Templates não esta funcionando

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando criar blocos dentro do meu template base (index.html), mas aparentemente o bloco não é usado.

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Portfolio's</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'content/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Oswald|Port+Lligat+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
     .
     .
     .
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div id='artigo' class='col-lg-8'>

                {% block corpo_artigo %}

                {% endblock %}
     .
     .
     .
```

Quando eu chamo ele em um arquivo separado, o mesmo não é efetivado

**corpo_artigo.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block corpo_artigo %}

    {% for item in conteudo_artigo%}

        {% if item.photo %}
        <img src="{{item.photo}}" class="img-responsive" alt="..."> 
        {% endif %}

            <a id='titulo' href="/artigos/{{item.id}}"><h1>{{item.titulo}}</h1></a>
            <h5 id ='autor'>{{item.autor}}</h5>
            <h5 id ='tag'>{{item.tag}}</h5>

            {% if item.corpo|length > 1000 %}
                <p id = 'corpo_artigo'>{{item.corpo|truncatewords:200|safe}}</p> 
                <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"> <a href="/artigos/{{item.id}}">Continue lendo</a></button>
            {% else %}
                <p>{{item.corpo}}</p>
            {% endif%}
                <h5 id ='data'>{{item.data}}</h5>

        {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**Obs** estou usando um diretório chamado templates usando:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

**EDIT:**
Notei que a tag {% extends "index.html"%} funciona normalmente, porém tudo que eu coloco dentro dos {% block % não funciona.

[image: 'extends' funciona.]

Comment: Por que você estar usando uma tag de estilo dentro de um bloco ? não seria mais fácil apenas chamar a folha de estilo ?  no django basta criar uma pasta chamada static e colocar a folha de estilo la depois criar olink para a mesma no html usando   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />

Comment: Sim , acho que não fui muito feliz com meu exemplo. Na verdade eu sei dessa funcionalidade, mas o problema persiste com **qualquer** elemento que eu bote dentro de um bloco.

Comment: pode informar se ocorre algum erro ? ou apenas não aparece o template ?

Comment: Simplesmente não aparece o template. Se eu usar apenas o {% extends "index.html" %} ele estende o código da pagina index, mas se eu colocar algo dentro de algum bloco ele não exibe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durante minhas pesquisas percebi que esse tipo de erro é uma coisa recorrente no que diz respeito a herança de Templates então decidi deixar aqui a solução para o problema e se possível contribuir com o conhecimento de outros que venham a cair no mesmo impasse.

Acredito que a confusão se dê em como a tag {%extends%} funciona. Os exemplos dados na documentação e em alguns posts espalhados pela web levam a crer que ela se comporta como um 'include', mas na verdade ela **nao** tem nada a ver com isso.

A Tag {%extends%} **realmente** *extende* o conteudo de uma determinada página para outra.
Pode parecer trivial, mas vou dar um exemplo que elucida tal comportamento, para isso vamos começar do inicio:

**urls.py**

```
from heranca import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$', views.home), #Exemplo simles de URL 
]
```

Criamos uma URL simples e importamos nossa view chamada 'home'.

**heranca/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Aqui é que vem a principal confusão. Seria intuitivo chamar um html que seja de fato nosso html base mas na verdade o que devemos chamar na nossa view é **o html onde nossos blocos vão ficar**, gerando assim um outro html que sirva como um esqueleto.

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'esqueleto.html'%}
{% block conteudo %}
   <p> Ja o conteudo presente dentro dos blocos apareceria somente caso o bloco seja devidamente declarado na pagina 'esqueleto'
    Dessa forma a pagina 'esqueleto' age como um esqueleto do nosso site possibilitando rodar elementos que são comuns a 
    todas as páginas.
   </p>
 {% endblock%}
```

Dessa forma devemos armazenar na página 'esqueleto' o conteúdo que queremos que realmente seja pertinente a outras paginas que façam referencia a ele.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Teste de herança </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
    <h1>Titulo do site</h1>
    <p>O conteudo presente na pagina 'esqueleto' será comum a pagina 'index' pois a mesma 'extende' seu conteudo a partir da tag 'extends'</p>

    {% block conteudo%}

    {% endblock%}
</div>
```

Se você reler a pergunta desse post vai perceber que lá a tag {% extends %} estava sendo usada de forma semelhante a um *include* em python, quando a mesma funciona de forma diferente.

Espero contribuir para a comunidade de alguma forma com isso.
[Esse post me ajudou a chegar a essa conclusão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175641/django-template-inheritance-how-to-not-display-block-from-parent)